# Non-Standard computer PCB, finding enclosure to mount

Tags: pcb, mount

Edit******
Thank you for replies. My bad for not including the board! Here it is:

Its the NVidia Jetson TK1.

There is a thread, for example, here, with a list of compatible enclosures. http://elinux.org/Jetson/Enclosures. I might get one of the 3D printed ones. OTOH, there is something I prefer more which is the Silverstone PT13, but it looks like the board is plopped into the case without the screws being installed. I'm unsure if this is proper practice and if the board would short-out as a result. Plan on using this board quite a bit so having it on several hours at a time won't be unusual.

Edit******

I'm a computer hobbyist looking to learn embedded programming on a specific platform and searching for a case to accommodate the non-standard size PCB (compared to PC case standards).

Board is 127 x 127 mm.

Power supplied via external power supply brick.

**My main concern is the PCB standoffs**. I don't know much about this issue. My only experience in this issue is assembling PCs where I line up motherboard to ATX mounts in the case and screw the board in.

I've found 3d printed options covering the top and bottom only of the board. Its an option but I prefer an enclosure/case to keep the board more protected from dust and pets.

What options do I have to mount the board? I don't want to leave the board in the open sitting on cardboard or a desk. I'd prefer if the board were held in place and in a proper traditional case/enclosure. The board doesn't include a backplane and I don't care much for one so long as the board is covered from all sides with hole for cables for keyboard and such. Board does generate heat so there will need to be vents in the case / enclosure.

Thanks in advance for feedback.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the 127x127 board?  Its important to know where the mounting holes are to see if they line up with some standardized holes.

Comment: A link to the manual of the board (single board computer?) would help.  There may be a mechanical drawing there (along with other useful info).

Comment: Added edit with info on the board. Manuals are here : https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads

Comment: Too late now, but you could've made one out of cardboard :)

Answer (score 2):

With limited information regarding the board and it's mounting hole pattern, it's hard to give specific information.

What I would recommend for enclosing general purpose large boards would be a 1U or 2U rackmount enclosure. They are fairly common for electronic equipment. If you lay your board inside it, you can mark the mounting holes with a sharpee and then drill the holes out. Once you have your custom hole pattern you can use some stand offs to secure it in place. You'll also need a few screws. You might consider using nylon standoffs if you want electrical isolation or the PCB mounting holes are connected to the ground plane. Below are a couple of links to get you started:

2U rackmount chasis (435mm x 295mm x 80mm): $39.95 http://www.circuitspecialists.com/rackmount-enclosure-37-2u.html

PCB heck standoff 1/2": http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/2203/36-2203-ND/82512

Comment: My rep is too low for 3 links. Screws can be found here: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PMSSS%20440%200025%20PH/H703-ND/274914

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about the back plane,  then all you need to do is tap and mount standard metal screw stand offs. Or rivet stand offs or nylon push stand offs or weld. You simply make your own mount points. Any enclosure will work at that point. Assuming your board has mount holes.

Otherwise, some boards, depending on size, weight, and vibration, you can mount it with foam tape/squares.